# How to pull through pages according to template name in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to modify the behaviour of the homepage of a theme I'm using. At the moment the homepage pulls through all artist **pages** in the site - it's doing this by featured image at the moment. So all artist pages have a featured image added to the page. This is the code in functions.php:

```
function my_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'page ') );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_thumbnail_id' );
        $query->set('orderby', 'rand');
        $query->set('posts_per_page', '100');
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
```

Only now I want to be able to add featured images to other pages in the site for other reasons, but don't want them to appear on the homepage. Each artist page is assigned to an 'artist.php' template, so I'm assuming it must be pretty straightforward to alter that function to **only pull in pages with the assigned template** rather than featured image.

After some searching on how other people have done something similar, I amended my code to the following:

```
function my_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'page ') );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_wp_page_template' );
        $query->set( 'meta_value', 'artist.php' );
        $query->set('orderby', 'rand');
        $query->set('posts_per_page', '100');
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
```

This breaks altogether and pulls nothing through. What am I missing here?!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It would be quite easy to put all artists in a specific category and exclude that category from the query. Would that be an option?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

I guess that could work yes, I was keen to get it to work with template name though as the pages I want pulling through are already assigned to artists.php...and there are a lot of them! 

How would you suggest I do it in that way?